# How to get precise correlation factor for two flat signals in python?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, curve, flat

At the moment I am struggeling with a correlation check of two time uniform signals, which are stored in a Pandas dataframe. If I use Pandas correlation function in Python for flat graphs I get unexpected and inconsistent results for my correlation factor.

My ideal case is shown in Fig. 1, where both signals rises and the correlation factor is 0.9909.

**Fig. 1**: Ideal case (Corr_fac = 0.9909)

[image]

But when there is only a very small change in the signal, I get inconsistent results. I expect to get a good correlation factor for both cases shown in Fig. 2 and 3. But the correlation factor for the case in Fig. 2 results in a correlation factor of 0.788 and for the other case a factor of 0.0427.

Fig. 2: Corr_fac = 0.788

[image: 2]

Fig. 3: Corr_fac = 0.0427

[image: 3]

I already tried the other correlation methods, i. e. Kendall and Spearsman, but they do not fix my problem.

Here is my code:

```py
corr_fac = df_signal[[sig1, sig2].corr(method="pearson")
```

Does anyone knows a Python module or another method that can give precise correlation results for flat curves?

Comment: Without the actual/sample data, it's hard to tell what when wrong. Also, it might be better if you can scale/translate the signals so as they are closer to each other in the plot. Or scatter one against the other. That helps see the correlation much better.

Comment: 2 ideas - try generating some really simple sample data with a known correlation (ie. two identical linear functions) to make sure your python snippet is doing what you think its doing.

- also Quang has a good idea -- try removing the constant offset before plotting, maybe that will show more deviation in the functions than we can see now